# Search for text by re.search from different locations in HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to write a conditional statement to search emails in:

- User Bio
- if not found to search in User Info
- elif not found as it might be missing return somthing like "N/A"

I have tried several ways but I am either receiving an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` or not getting the desired outcome.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
email_list = []

url = input("Link")

r = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
name_array = soup.find_all('h1', {'class': 'class1'})

bio = soup.find('div', {'class': 'UserBio'}).text
info=soup.find('div', {'class': 'UserInfo'}).text

try:
    email = re.search('\S+@\S+', bio).group()
    print(email+"bio")
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
try:
    email = re.search('\S+@\S+', info).group()
    print(email + "info")
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
print(email)
email_list.append(email)
```

The reason why I have used Try except is that an error is generated as Attribute Error.

**My desired outcome is:**

1. Search for Email in User Bio
2. If it is not available in User Bio Search for Email in User Info.
3. elif it is not available in User Info to Append it as "N/A"

Answer (score 0):

The search() function can return None if no match.  so if you have no match your search line is effectively:

```
email = None.group()
```

You need to check the results of the search for None before calling a method if its not none to get the email info.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for the question so I wanted to contribute it:
Search for Email in User Bio:

```
while email_found == None:
        if soup.find_all(class_="UserBio"):
            for my_tag in soup.find_all(class_="UserBio"):
                emails = re.findall(EMAIL_REGEX, my_tag.text)
                email = None if not emails else emails
                if email != None:
                    print(email)
                    email_list.append(email[0])
                    print(email_list, "1")
                    email_found = True
                break
            else:
                email = None
                print("None 1 in UserBio")
        else:
            email=None
            print("None 1 in User Info 1")
        if soup.find('a', {'class': 'UserInfo'}):
            EMAIL_REGEX = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
            new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_r.text, 'html.parser')
            email_elements = new_soup.find('a', {'class':'link'}).text.strip().split()
                    email=email_elements[0]
                    email_list.append(email)
                    print(email_list, "3")
                    email_found = True
                    break
        else:
            email = None
            break
    if email_found == None:
        email = "N/A"
        email_list.append(email)
```